# Lottie for iOS Example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, after-effects

I'm fairly new to animations, and I'm trying to get the following library to work:  https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios

It takes animations that are created in After Effects and exported as JSON using bodymovin (https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin)

I've made a simple test animation and have exported it as JSON (called data.json). I made a simple test app in Xcode, added the Lottie framework, and added data.json to the bundle. I'm just trying to get the animation to display on startup, here's what I have in viewDidLoad that isn't working:

```
NSString *myFilePath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];

LOTAnimationView *testAnimation = [LOTAnimationView animationFromJSON:jsonDict];

[self.view addSubview:testAnimation];

[testAnimation play];

NSLog(@"subviews - %@", self.view.subviews);
NSLog(@"testanim - %@", testAnimation.description);
if (testAnimation.isAnimationPlaying)
{
    NSLog(@"is playing");
}
```

All I get is a blank white screen. In the console, I can see the subview was added, and also the log from isAnimationPlaying. I can also log jsonDict.description and I see that the JSON is in there. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the JSON file I'm using: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=15724557118327374873

Comment: Try doing it in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks, moved [testAnimation play] and the log to viewDidAppear and it's still blank, the console says it's playing though.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, the issue is with my data.json file. I swapped in one of their example animation files and I'm able to get it to display. Maybe I used an unsupported feature or something, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues like this that I've seen in my own animations.

First, make sure that your subview has a valid frame when it's displayed. I didn't dig too far into it, but sometimes I don't see anything until I've properly added view constraints to the animation view.

Second, double check your animation to make sure it isn't relying on image assets, as that's not currently supported.